# Rsync "succeeds" but actually fails over ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync, backup

I am experiencing a problem in setting up an `rsync` over `ssh` from my mac laptop to an Ubuntu server.

Basically my command line works like a charm with external drives, synchronizing directories and pushing only changed files. When using `ssh` the command **succeeds** but in reality **it does not write anything** on the server.

This is a test I have tried with some useless basic files (on the mac laptop):

```
~% mkdir foobar

~% cd foobar 

foobar% echo "test1" > a.txt

foobar% echo "test2" > b.txt

foobar% cd ..
```

Then the syncronization:

```
% rsync -a --delete -h -v -n "/Users/sensei/foobar" senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com:~/  
senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com's password: 
building file list ... done
foobar/
foobar/a.txt
foobar/b.txt

sent 133 bytes  received 38 bytes  31.09 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.07
```

The command succeeded, but if I `ssh` one the linux server, nothing has been written. This is also confirmed by running `rsync` a second time without modifying any files:

```
~% rsync -a --delete -h -v -n "/Users/sensei/foobar" senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com:~/
senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com's password: 
building file list ... done
foobar/
foobar/a.txt
foobar/b.txt

sent 133 bytes  received 38 bytes  38.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.07
```

I don't know what I am missing here, so I've run `rsync` verbosely:

```
~% rsync -a --delete -h -vvvvv -n "/Users/sensei/foobar" "senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com:~/"
cmd= machine=ssh.w.name.com user=senseilinux path=~/
cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=-l cmd[2]=senseilinux cmd[3]=ssh.w.name.com cmd[4]=rsync cmd[5]=--server cmd[6]=-vvvvvnlogDtpr cmd[7]=--delete cmd[8]=. cmd[9]=~/ 
opening connection using ssh -l senseilinux ssh.w.name.com rsync --server -vvvvvnlogDtpr --delete . "~/" 
senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com's password: 
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=24, EXTRA_LEN=4
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=29
(Server) Protocol versions: remote=29, negotiated=29
building file list ... 
[sender] make_file(foobar,*,2)
[sender] make_file(foobar/b.txt,*,2)
[sender] make_file(foobar/a.txt,*,2)
done
server_recv(2) starting pid=58290
[sender] i=0 /Users/sensei foobar/ mode=040755 len=128 uid=501 gid=20 flags=1
[sender] i=1 /Users/sensei foobar/a.txt mode=0100644 len=6 uid=501 gid=20 flags=0
[sender] i=2 /Users/sensei foobar/b.txt mode=0100644 len=6 uid=501 gid=20 flags=0
send_file_list done
file list sent
send_files starting
recv_file_name(foobar)
recv_file_name(foobar/b.txt)
recv_file_name(foobar/a.txt)
received 3 names
uid 501(sensei) maps to 501
process has 2 gids:  27 1034
gid 20(staff) maps to 50
[Receiver] flist_eof=1
[Receiver] flist start=0, used=3, low=0, high=2
[Receiver] i=0 1 foobar/ mode=040755 len=128 gid=(50) flags=405
[Receiver] i=1 2 foobar/a.txt mode=0100644 len=6 gid=(50) flags=400
[Receiver] i=2 2 foobar/b.txt mode=0100644 len=6 gid=(50) flags=400
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=3 /home/senseilinux/
[Receiver] change_dir(/home/senseilinux)
generator starting pid=58290
deleting in foobar
[generator] pushing local filters for /home/senseilinux/foobar/a.txt/
[generator] pushing local filters for /home/senseilinux/foobar/b.txt/
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(foobar,0)
send_files(0, /Users/sensei/foobar)
foobar/
recv_generator(foobar/a.txt,1)
recv_generator(foobar/b.txt,2)
generate_files phase=1
send_files(1, /Users/sensei/foobar/a.txt)
foobar/a.txt
send_files(2, /Users/sensei/foobar/b.txt)
foobar/b.txt
send_files phase=1
recv_files(3) starting
recv_files(foobar)
recv_files(foobar/a.txt)
recv_files(foobar/b.txt)
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0
recv_files phase=2
generate_files phase=3
recv_files finished
generate_files finished
client_run waiting on 12185

sent 133 bytes  received 38 bytes  38.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.07
_exit_cleanup(code=0, file=/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c, line=996): entered
_exit_cleanup(code=0, file=/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c, line=996): about to call exit(0)
```

Apparently, everything is good. Nothing on the server, though.

Not only that, there is *no problem* at all if I `scp` files to the server:

```
~% scp -r foobar senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com:
senseilinux@ssh.w.name.com's password: 
b.txt                                                                                                                       100%    6     0.5KB/s   00:00    
a.txt                                                                                                                       100%    6     0.5KB/s   00:00    

# ON THE LINUX SERVER:

~$ ls foobar/
a.txt  b.txt
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `rsync -n`, you will not copy anything to the destination.

The `-n` option to `rsync` is the same as `--dry-run`, i.e. "perform a trial run with no changes made" (wording taken from the manual).

Remove `-n` from the command line and try again.

Comment: Aw man... I didn't see that, now I really feel stupid wasting an hour like that!